# upvote and reputation points

Tags: discussion, support

Could someone please enlighten me on these :)

1. Do upvoted comments (not answers) get any reputation points?
2. Do upvoted posts in meta contribute to any extent to one's reputation points, or if not, where do the upvotes go to?

Many thanks in anticipation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Comment votes do not reward reputation, but in some cases they may result in [badges](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/pundit).
2. Votes received in Meta do not impact your reputation -- your meta user's reputation is synced periodically from the main site. Voting in meta serves to express community sentiment for a topic or viewpoint. [Help Center: What's Meta?](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: If a bronze badge could be made available for comments (apart from this silver one, it would be much appreciated. .

Comment: That kind of change would be platform-wide and as such is not likely to happen. SE considers their interaction model very carefully--many aspects of the site are expressly designed to incentivize high-quality content, and I believe I've even heard Joel Spolksy say he wishes he could have made comments temporary instead of persistent. This might be useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Comment: Bronze badge would make much sense in the SE model of badges. Badges are there to actively reward actions that the user takes. Leaving 10 comments gives a bronze badge, because the encouraged action is: comment. However, getting one upvote for a comment is no achievement, these votes are really quite random. So only getting 50 of them means: Oh, this guy knows to help the situation by the comments if he gets upvoted so much.